# PHP-Javascript interaction

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

So I've been attempting to get this page to work correctly for the past few days.  As far as the database manipulation and what not it works like a charm.  The problem is that it apparently isn't hitting my javascript function to redirect back onto itself.  It will instead show a mostly blank page with no $_GET variables in the url which leads me to believe the problem is actually in my php function rather than my javascript function.

```
function edit_player()
{

try{
    if( isset( $_GET['player_id'] ) )
    {
        if( isset( $_GET['success'] ) && $_GET['success'] )
        {
            echo "<div class='success'> You have successfully edited this players info.</div>" ;
        }
        $playerid = $_GET['player_id'] ;
        $db = honneyconnect( ) ;  // db connection established
        if( mysqli_connect_error() )
        {
            throw new Exception( "Could not connect to the database") ;
        }
        $query = 'select * from roster where player_number ="'.$playerid.'"' ;
        $player = $db->query( $query ) ;
        if( !$player  )
        {
            throw new Exception ( "Query returned zero results" ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            $row = $player->fetch_row() ;
            echo '
            <div class="data_entry">
            <form id="player_info" method="post" action="editplayer.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000000" />
            <input type="hidden" name="player_number" value="'.$row[0].'" />
            <table>
            <tr><td>Player Number:</td><td>'.$row[0].'</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Player Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="50" name="name" value="'.$row[1].'"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Player Position:</td><td><input type="text" size="20" name="position" value="'.$row[2].'" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Years Skating:</td><td><input type="text" size="3" name="years" value="'.$row[3].'"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>How You Chose Your Derby Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="100" name="choice" value="'.$row[4].'" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Life Outside of Derby:</td><td><input type="text" size="100" name="life" value="'.$row[5].'" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Current Photo: </td><td><img class="thumbnail" src="rosterpics/'.$row[6].'"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Choose a different photo:</td><td><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Sponsor:</td><td><input type="text" size="50" name="sponsors" value="'.$row[7].'"/></td></tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
            </form></div>' ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( isset($_POST['player_number']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['position'])
        && isset($_POST['years']) && isset($_POST['choice']) && isset($_POST['life']) )
        {
            if( !file_exists( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] ) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] ) )
            {
                $db = honneyconnect( ) ;  // db connection established
                if( mysqli_connect_error() )
                {
                    throw new Exception( "Could not connect to the database") ;
                }
                $query = 'update roster set player_name = "'.$_POST['name'].'" ,
                    player_position = "'.$_POST['position'].'", player_years = "'.$_POST['years'].'" , player_choice = "'.$_POST['choice'].'",
                        player_life = "'.$_POST['life'].'" where player_number = "'.$_POST['player_number'].'"' ;
                $player = $db->query( $query ) ;
                if( !$player )
                {
                    throw new Exception( "Query failed" ) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    if( isset($_POST['sponsors']) )
                    {
                        $query = 'update roster set player_sponsor = "'.$_POST['sponsors'].'" where player_number = "'.$_POST['player_number'].'"';
                        $sponsor = $db->query( $query ) ;
                        if( !$sponsor )
                        {
                            throw new Exception( "Failed to update sponsor." ) ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $url = "http://localhost/honeysproject/editplayer.php?player_id=".$_POST['player_number']."" ;
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>success_redirect( ".$url." ) ;</script>" ;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $url = "http://localhost/honeysproject/editplayer.php?player_id=".$_POST['player_number']."" ;
                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>success_redirect( ".$url." ) ;</script>" ;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if( $_FILES['photo']['size'] > 50000000 )
                {
                    throw new Exception( "File is to large for this server." );
                }
                if( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "C:/wamp/www/HoneysProject/rosterpics/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]) )
                {
                    throw new Exception( "There was a problem uploading the file" ) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    $db = honneyconnect( ) ;  // db connection established
                    if( mysqli_connect_error() )
                    {
                    throw new Exception( "Could not connect to the database") ;
                    }
                    $query = 'update roster set player_name = "'.$_POST['name'].'" ,
                    player_position = "'.$_POST['position'].'", player_years = "'.$_POST['years'].'" , player_choice = "'.$_POST['choice'].'",
                        player_life = "'.$_POST['life'].'", player_photo = "'.$_FILES['photo']['name'].'" where player_number = "'.$_POST['player_number'].'"' ;
                    $player = $db->query( $query ) ;
                    if( !$player )
                    {
                        throw new Exception( "Query failed" ) ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if( isset($_POST['sponsors']) )
                        {
                            $query = 'update roster set player_sponsor = "'.$_POST['sponsors'].'" where player_number = "'.$_POST['player_number'].'"';
                            $sponsor = $db->query( $query ) ;
                            if( !$sponsor )
                            {
                                throw new Exception( "Failed to update sponsor." ) ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $url = "http://localhost/honeysproject/editplayer.php?player_id=".$_POST['player_number']."" ;
                                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>success_redirect( ".$url."  );</script>" ;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $url = "http://localhost/honeysproject/editplayer.php?player_id=".$_POST['player_number']."" ;
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>success_redirect( ".$url." ) ;</script>" ;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
catch( Exception $error )
{
    echo "<div class='error'>".$error."</div>" ;
    echo $_FILES['photo']['name'] ;
}
}



<html>
<head>
<style>
@import "honeysstyle.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function success_redirect( url )
{
    window.location.replace( url ) ;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require( 'function.php' );

draw_masthead();
edit_player() ;


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success_redirect( ".$url." ) 

should be

success_redirect( '".$url." ')
```

and why don't you use the header function

```
header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Wow thank you.  I've honestly never even seen nor heard of the header() function.  If what I'm reading is correct it will basically take the place of all my javascript redirect code correct?